# MongoDB(Wired tiger) : Upsert errors with "duplicate key error" - Multi Threaded

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have faced the following error in our application while `upsert` in `mongodb`:

**Exception**

```
com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server
Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: index: _id_ dup key: { : 
at com.mongodb.connection.BulkWriteBatchCombiner.getError(BulkWriteBatchCombiner.java:176) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.BulkWriteBatchCombiner.throwOnError(BulkWriteBatchCombiner.java:205) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.BulkWriteBatchCombiner.getResult(BulkWriteBatchCombiner.java:146) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:159) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:141) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:186) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:177) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar:na]
```

**Ref**

After searching, have identified that there are two open issue in `JIRA`:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14322

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20022

Note: Our application is multithreaded. Two different threads are performing bulk upserts.

**Question**

What is an alternative for this to be coded on the application side in Java to avoid failure and update the document with proper values?

Comment: Curious. Since this seems to apply to WT only ([my answer why I don't use it in production at the moment](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121160/mongodb-mmapv1-vs-wiredtiger-storage-engines/121170#121170)), a simple approach would be to change the storage engine, which should be possible without downtime in a replica set / sharded cluster backed by replica sets. As per Java side: you'd have to synchronize on the object to write, which would be odd as a workaround for a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the update...@MarkusWMahlberg..as we have our code as clustered(two instances of the application on two different machines)  synchronize wont be solving the issue on the java side..any other alternatives?